# How to get text from a webpage from the command line?

Tags: command-line, automator

I am looking for a command line equivalent to the `Get text from webpage` option in `/Applications/Automator.app`. The `Get text from webpage`option is pretty self explanatory, it gets the text only, without HTML tags, CSS, JavaScript, etc. from a webpage. I know I can use `wget` or `curl` but that will give me all the HTML tags, CSS, JavaScript, etc. not the only text version of the webpage.

Comment: I don't know of any command to do this. You could try writing a PHP script that downloads the content then strips out all of the tags. That could still leave you with javascript or css depending on how the page is built. You'd need to strip that stuff with extra regexp first, then use strip_tags() to dump the rest.

Comment: Hmm. I'm looking for speed here do you think it would be quicker than just using the automator thing.

Comment: Web pages are pretty small, I think any solution is going to run very quickly. I don't know anything about the automator solution though.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help will look into the PHP script idea, and possibly run from command line with the `php` command.

Comment: Have you tried ‘curl’

Comment: @Allan Please read the question I explained why that won’t work.

Comment: Well, yeah...When you screen scrape, you need to know *what* you are looking for.  In other words, you grab what's in between the tags you're interested in with a text processor like `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: Could you give a command to do this?

Comment: Off  the bat you could do something like `curl https://apple.stackexchange.com | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'` and it will strip out the tags.  Taking it further, you could use this PHP code to do just what you asked:  http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/09/php_tip_how_strip_html_tags_web_page.  Though, with a page like this, it will give you irrelevant info.  Your best bet is to just find the text your're looking for.

Comment: How about: `curl -s 'https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322243/how-to-get-text-from-a-webpage-from-the-command-line' | textutil -stdin -stdout -convert txt`

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is the `textutil` command. Read the man page, but something like:

```
textutil -convert txt webpage.html
```

should work.

Comment: Can you please explain why `textutil` is better than other options?

Comment: It's simpler than a PHP script. It's more readable than sed.

Comment: I'll try it out soon. See if it works.

Comment: User user3439894 give an example in a comment above.  Ran an my mac just fine.

Comment: @historystamp if you want to address someone use the `@` followed by the name